# LINQ group by list and the the first/last for each grouped property

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I cannot figure out how to make this query with LINQ.
I have the following example class:

```
class Foo
{
    string Identifier {get; set;}
    int StartValue {get; set;}
    int EndValue {get; set;}
}
```

where `Identifier` is a unique identifier and `StartValue` and `EndValue` two integers.

I created the following list

```
List<Foo> myList = new List<Foo>()
myList.Add(new Foo { "11111", 1, 2 })
myList.Add(new Foo { "11111", 2, 3 })
myList.Add(new Foo { "11111", 3, 4 })
myList.Add(new Foo { "22222", 1, 2 })
```

Clearer input list

```
"11111" 1 2
"11111" 2 3
"11111" 3 4
"22222" 1 2
```

I'd like to group each element by the identifier and **associate to them the first `StartValue` and the last `EndValue`**.

For example I have three "11111" element, so in my output list I'd like to have one "11111" element with `StartValue` the first of the three startValues (1) and `EndValue` the last of the three EndValues (4).

Result List

```
"11111" 1 4
"22222" 1 2
```

How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group by the identifier and then select the first start value and the last endvalue - pretty much exactly as you describe it

```
var result = myList.GroupBy(x => x.Identifier)
      .Select(x => new { 
               Identifier = x.Key, 
               FirstStart = x.First().StartValue, 
               LastEnd = x.Last().EndValue });
```

You could also project back to your original object if you prefer that over an anonymous object.

Note that it's not entirely clear from your question whether you want the first/last or the min/max. If you wanted min max its almost the same as above

```
var result = myList.GroupBy(x => x.Identifier)
      .Select(x => new { 
               Identifier = x.Key, 
               MinStart = x.Min(y => y.StartValue), 
               MinEnd = x.Max(y => y.EndValue) });
```

And again, you could project this back to your class instead of an anonymous.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I first asked for min/max but I'd like to have first/last, as I edited. Many thanks for both the first/last and the max/min solutions, they works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
IEnumerable<Foo> result = myList.GroupBy(x => x.Identifier)
                                .Select(x => new Foo() {
                                    Identifier = x.Key, 
                                    StartValue = x.First().StartValue, 
                                    EndValue = x.Last().EndValue
                                });
```